# Displaying data randomly in Data Grid View in Windows Application using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a small assignment where I need to display data (0 to 99 - make sure all the numbers are displayed) randomly in a data grid view of 10 rows and 10 columns. I am unable to figure out the logic that needs to be written for this scenario. Currently I am doing like shown below, two for loops, one for row and other columns and iterating it...

```
        int[] arr = new int[] { 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 58, 69, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 };
        char c = Convert.ToChar(arr.GetValue(new Random().Next(0, 21)));

        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
            {
                if ((row + col) == 9)
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value = string.Format("{0}     {1}", c, ((row + 1) * 9));
                }
                else
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value = string.Format("{0}     {1}", Convert.ToChar(arr.GetValue(new Random().Next(0, 21))), row * 10 + (col));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
                }
            }
        }
```

Out put:

[image: Data Grid View Output]

Expected:

Code for randomly distributing the numbers from 0 to 99.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but for more reliable randomness, you should initialize a single instance of Random, store it, and call .Next() from it, instead of re-creating a new Random() inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was finally able to do it. It worked!!!

```
public static class ThreadSafeRandom
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Random Local;

    public static Random ThisThreadsRandom
    {
        get { return Local ?? (Local = new Random(unchecked(Environment.TickCount * 31 + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))); }
    }
}

static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = ThreadSafeRandom.ThisThreadsRandom.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code does the shuffling of numbers.

```
        var numbers = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 100));
        numbers.Shuffle();
        List<int> final = numbers.GetRange(0, 100);                                   

        int[,] f = new int[10, 10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                f[i, j] = final[(i * 10) + j];                    
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if (f[i, j] % 9 == 0)
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = string.Format("{0}     {1}", charSymbol, f[i, j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = string.Format("{0}     {1}", GetRandomChar(), f[i, j]);                       
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

By small assignment do you mean school assignment? If so, I don't want to write everything for you, but to point you in the right direction:

The first step I would take initializing an array with a size of 100, and placing the numbers 0-99 on the array. Then, I would find a method for shuffling the array (Linq's OrderBy used with the Random class may be useful to you here). Then, I would iterate through the shuffled array, and place those items inside the grid. I think you have the general grid looping idea down, with the embedded for loops... I'm not sure what the point of the Thread Sleep is, though.

Comment: When we use Random class without time interval of 15 milliseconds, there are chances of getting the same number. So I have put a delay of 15 ms. Thanks for your input, I got an idea how to implement this.

Comment: If you create a single Random object outside of the loops, and use .Next() from that single object, you should avoid the accidental duplication of integers without needing the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this if you ain't done with your coding...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        dt.Columns.Add("col" + i.ToString(), typeof(int));

    Random r = new Random();
    List<int> l = new List<int>(100);
    int temp=0;
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            temp = r.Next(99);
            if (!l.Contains(temp) || (j == 0 && i == 0))
            {
                dr["col" + j.ToString()] = temp;
                l.Add(temp);
            }
            else
                j -= 1;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chakri, however this code seems to be not working, which has an infinite loop. Also the Data Bind method does not exist for Data grid view in windows application.

Comment: OMG!! Infinite loop..!! But its working fine in my app

Comment: if (!l.Contains(temp) || (j == 0 && i == 0)) -> This where it is getting stucked...